# Statement in Date and time in AngularJS is not working..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Statement in Date and time in AngularJS is not working..?

"obj.schemeStartDate"  containing data in this format

`"Fri Oct 14 12:30:00 IST 2016"`

```
 var schemeDate = new Date(obj.schemeStartDate).getTime();
```

Comment: your code is only javascript, there is no use of any angular. and try to run in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"obj.schemeStartDate"` containing data in this format `"Fri Oct 14 12:30:00 IST 2016"`. The date string you are getting is invalid.

`new Date("Fri Oct 14 12:30:00 IST 2016")` throws your `Invalid Date`. The below works fine:

```
new Date("Fri Oct 14 12:30:00 2016")
```

Comment: Thank u very much Sir...